# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el Sender en un método TTimer?

Tags: delphi

Estoy tratando de mostrar una ventana emergente con un método que tiene 3 parámetros `ShowPreview(tag: integer; sender: TObject; mForm:Tform)`, este método está en un metodo `TTimer`, el problema es cuando estoy tratando de enviarlo como parámetro para obtener el `Sender`, obtengo esto error:

`Invalid class typecast`

Declaré una variable global para guardarlo, pero el error sigue saliendo

```
procedure TMainForm.TabLabelMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
      self.TimerTag:= Sender;
      //PreviewForm.ShowPreview(TElLabel(Sender).Tag, sender, self);
      TimerDisplayPreviewForm.Enabled:= true;
end;

procedure TMainForm.TimerDisplayPreviewFormTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
    //PreviewForm.ShowPreview(TElLabel(Sender).Tag, sender, self);
    //Showmessage(IntToStr(TimerTag));
    PreviewForm.ShowPreview((Sender as TComponent).Tag, sender, self);
    TimerDisplayPreviewForm.Enabled:= false;
end;
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el Sender de `TabLabelMouseEnter` para asignarlo en `TimerDisplayPreviewForm`?

Comment: Especifica bien tu problema y quiza se pueda resolver de una forma mas limpia y elegante

Comment: Creo que te equivocas de Sender, el del evento del Timer es el propio Timer.
Sustituye el uso de Sender por TimerTag, que habías guardado anteriormente.

Comment: @Japv basicamente es atrapar el `Sender` del metodo `TabLabelMouseEnter` para poder usar ese mismo `sender` que atrapé en el metodo `TimerDisplayPreviewFormTimer`

Comment: @Garada gracias